# How to make a page for every single object from JSON data - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I've JSON data
[{"name":"Zohir","id":"151232", "code":"ZO"},{"name":"Tuhhin","id":"151233", "code":"TU"}, .....]
I want to show every single object in different page & also i want to render a single student page based on "code", Like www.mylink.com/student/ZO

I don't know is my question correct or not, I'm new in JavaScript

I tried to show all data in a page from JSON file & i did that, but i can't render a single student page

```
function getStudent() {
    fetch('https://myjesondatas123211.herokuapp.com/v/students')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
        let output = '<h2>Students</h2>'
        data.forEach(function (student) {
            output += `
                <div class="col-md-4">
               <h4>${student.name}</h4>
                   <p>${student.id}</p>
               <p>${student.code}</p>
            </div>
            `;
        });
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = output;
    })
};
```

Comment: For a URL like `www.mylink.com/student/ZO` to work, you will need to look into server-side rewriting, this part isn’t one that client-side JavaScript can handle all on its own (at least not in a sensible fashion.)

Comment: What exactly is "_page_" in this context?

Comment: @Teemu I mean show every single student in different page www.mylink.com/student/ZO www.mylink.com/student/TU

Comment: @ so can't show every single student

Comment: @04FS That is not correct, it is certainly possible to solve this problem in client side JavaScript. Dynamic page rendering is used a lot in today's world.

Comment: You can, but as 04FS said, you've to do this at the server-side, unless you want to open a new tab/pop-up window for every page.

Comment: @JesseVermeulen you still need to set up _something_ on the server side to provide the same base document in response to all those requests for `/student/ZO`, `/student/TU` etc. to begin with. If you do not create those as physical files or folders, and don’t have any dynamic, server-side URL rewriting in place to handle these requests either, they would simply get a 404 response. […]

Comment: […] You can maybe dynamically handle this stuff one the client side once you have the basic app loaded - but if I start using it by accessing `/student/ZO` directly, as the first, initial request I make from within my browser, the server still has to respond appropriately.

Comment: @04FS so i can make only a hash based router

Comment: @04FS You can just tell your webserver to rewrite every request to the root URL/root files.
That way you don't need to create a server side route for every possibility and gives you the control to do front-end routing.

Comment: @JesseVermeulen so, that’s still a part that needs to be done on the server side. Whether you do the _majority_ of the routing work on the server or the client doesn’t matter, but the server side can not be kept _completely_ out of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution to this problem would be fairly complex to create in plain Javascript.
You would need to have an understanding about **single page applications** and **routers** to start tackling this problem.

You might want to look over here or search for another tutorial to get the basics: 
https://dev.to/rishavs/making-a-single-page-app-in-ye-good-olde-js-es6-3eng

Answer (score 0):

You want to do a single-page app, which is not simple in plain javascript.
You may want to consider using frameworks for this, such as Angular or React to do this quite easily
They have native routers and allow you to create routes with parameters, and display a component depending on this parameter.

Comment: Thank you but i want to make it plain JavaScript, 
any idea?